# Javascript for .. of loop (ECMAScript 6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So new ECMAScript 6 has introduced `for .. of` loop syntax.

Unfortunately, there aren't many documentations out there that explains what this really does. As in how it differs from using `Array.prototype.forEach` or `for .. in` loop.

Is it just another imperative way to perform `Array.prototype.forEach`?

I've already read Mozilla's doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). But still the idea is too vague to me.

Anyone cares to explain to this halfwit?

Comment: Read the pages on iterators and generators. In particular the new iterator protocol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Quick hint**

**`for..of` takes the element.**

```
var a = ['a','b','c'];

for (let elem of a){
    console.log(elem);
}
// output: 
// 'a'
// 'b'
// 'c'
```

**`for..in` takes the index.**

```
var a = ['a','b','c'];

for (let i in a){
    console.log(i);
}
// output:
// 0
// 1
// 2
```

**`.forEach` takes element and index (optional).**

```
var a = ['a','b','c'];

a.forEach(function(elem,i){
    console.log(i + ': ' + elem);
});
// output:
// 0: 'a'
// 1: 'b'
// 2: 'c'
```

Comment: Saying `for...in` takes the index is a very unsafe thing to say, it takes all enumerable properties, anywhere in the prototype chain, not just indexes. `for(var prop in obj)` === `for (var prop of Reflect.enumerate(obj))`

Comment: `for ([elem, i] of a.entries()) …` does take both as well!

Comment: Another point would be that `forEach` is a method of the prototype of a fixed set of functions. `for..of` works on any *iterable* object

Answer (score 1):

From mdn doc:

> While for...in iterates over property names, for...of iterates over property values.

What else need to be clear?

Answer (score 0):

Take this example:

```
var items = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for (let item of items) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

It's essentially equivalent to:

```
var items = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i]); // outputs: a, b, c, d
}
```

As you can see, `for...of` iterates only over an iterable object's *values* while `for...in` iterates over any object's property *names*.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) iterates each element in array but  [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop iterates object using iterable protocol.

For example when you override built-in array's iterator results could be different:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

arr[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
}

for (let value of arr) {
    console.log(value)
}
// output: 1, 2, 3

arr.forEach(value => console.log(value));
// output: a, b, c
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess that the implement of Array.prototype.forEach is like this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback) 
    for(var index = 0; index < arrayObject.length; index++) [
        callback(arrayObject[index], index, arrayObject);
    }
}
```

That means, the execution of callback function in Array.prototype.forEach is asynchronous, but the progress in a for ... in loop is synchronized.

If I'm wrong, please rectify it.

Comment: A callback does not mean something is asynchronous. Example: `var func = function(callback) { callback(); }; func(function() { alert('test'); });`